# Getting the DataType inside an HDF5 ArrayType

Tags: c++, hdf5

In the C++ bindings for HDF5, I can create a 1x4 `H5::ArrayType` made up of doubles with an expression like

```
H5::ArrayType array_type(H5::PredType::IEEE_F64LE,1,4);
```

If I am just given `array_type`, how do I find out its underlying `H5::DataType` (in this case `IEEE_F64LE`).  The methods for  the `H5::ArrayType` class only give me a way to find out the size of the array, but not the underlying type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [`H5::DataType::getSuper()`](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/class_h5_1_1_data_type.html#ab3454be65ac1830f2b68ec745155d749) which you can use on `array_type` since `H5::ArrayType` inherits from `H5::DataType`.